# How to put zeros before number in SQL

Tags: sql

I have this

```
select 
    b.min::integer, a.id_immoble,a.planta, a.num_via, a.escalera, 
    a.bloque, a.refcat, 
    right('0000' + cast( a.id_immoble as varchar(4)), 4) 
from 
    paola.cadastre_amb_immoble  a
```

but I get an error from the second line:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: unknown + character varying
> LINE 3: ...via, a.escalera, a.bloque, a.refcat, right('0000' + CAST( a....
> ^
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> SQL state: 42883
> Character: 106

I expected that the result of number 1 was 0001, or the number 234 was 0234

Comment: `+` for concatenating strings is non-standard, some DBMS use it, others use a different operator, e.g. postgreSQL uses `||`. You might try [`CONCAT`](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/func_sqlserver_concat.asp) function instead, it is more widely supported (though apparently non-standard as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are having is telling you that there is an issue with the concatenation operator in the SQL query. I assume that you are using PostgreSQL, so for the concatenation operator for string values, it is `||` instead of `+`.

To modify your query and resolve the error, you can replace the `+` operator with `||`. Here's the updated query:

```sql
SELECT
  b.min::integer,
  a.id_immoble,
  a.planta,
  a.num_via,
  a.escalera,
  a.bloque,
  a.refcat,
  RIGHT('0000' || CAST(a.id_immoble AS varchar(4)), 4)
FROM
  paola.cadastre_amb_immoble a;
```

Comment: Thak you. It worked with the ||

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT id_immoble, TO_CHAR(id_immoble, 'fm0000') FROM paola.cadastre_amb_immoble
```